# Enable field search without field column model show

Tags: search, jqgrid, hidden

I wish I could hide a column in the list of records but in the search dialog display it. How i do it?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can define `search: false` for any column in the `colModel` (see http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options). This will disables searching on that column.

In general if you want to hide the column you use typically `hidden: true` in the [column model definition](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:colmodel_options). jqGrid not display hidden columns in the searching dialog if you explicitly not enable another behavior with `searchhidden: true` in the `searchoptions` (see http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:search_config#colmodel_options)